# Room Dao inheritance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Is is it possible to have a Dao with a non annotated method? And override it in the derived classes?

```
interface DaoBase<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : Entity<TId> {

    @Insert
    fun add(entity: TEntity)

    fun get(id: TId): TEntity?

    @Update
    fun update(entity: TEntity)
}

fun <TEntity, TId> DaoBase<TEntity, TId>.addOrUpdate(entity: TEntity) where TEntity : Entity<TId> {
    val entityQ = get(entity.id)
    if(entityQ == null) {
        add(entity)
    } else {
        update(entity)
    }
}
```

I get this error for the DaoBase object:

```
DaoBase.java:13: error: An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery
    public abstract TEntity get(TId id);
```

And the same error on any Dao that inherits from it. I think the code that generates the code may have a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add @Query above get

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id=:id")  
fun get(id: TId): TEntity?
```

Also you can forgo your addOrUpdate function, and your update function

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun add(entity: TEntity)
```

which is the same as updating

Comment: Thank you. I just found that conflict strategy option, so I'll be checking that out. You can't add an empty @Query annotation, though with OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE I don't even need to have the get method, because I don't need the AddOrUpdate. I had to get method so that the DaoBase would know about it for the AddOrUpdate.